# Как проверить введенную строку с паролем

Tags: java, spring-security

Задача следующая: есть личный кабинет где пользователь может поменять свой пароль предварительно введя текущий.

Как можно проверить введенный текст на соответствие пароля в бд?

Код тестового пароля:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/account", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView accountEdit(@RequestParam("account") String user1, HttpServletRequest request) {
    User user = userService.findByEmail(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("user", user);
    modelAndView.setViewName("account");

    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    if (!email.isEmpty()) {
        user.setEmail(email);
    }
    String username = request.getParameter("name");
    if (!username.isEmpty()) {
        user.setUsername(username);
    }

    String currentPassword = request.getParameter("currentPassword");
    String newPassword = request.getParameter("newPassword");
    String confirmPassword = request.getParameter("confirmPassword");

    if (!newPassword.isEmpty() && !confirmPassword.isEmpty()) {
        if(!newPassword.equals(confirmPassword)) {
            modelAndView.addObject("errorMessage", "Пароли не совпадают");
            return modelAndView;
        }
        user.setPassword(newPassword);
        userService.saveUser(user);
        System.out.println(user.getPassword());
        return modelAndView;
    }

    modelAndView.addObject("user", user);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Пароли хранятся в зашифрованном виде и в лоб их сравнить не получается

Answer (score 1):

1. Вытащите зашифрованный пароль из БД
2. Зашифруйте пароль от пользователя так же как шифровали во время установки пароля.
3. Сравните пароль из БД и зашифрованный от пользователя

Comment: шифровал bcrypt. и шифр одного и того же пароля "11111111" не совпадает password from form + encrypt: $2a$10$CxRl5725w.IQsgmjSGSY0u.EYROA3wiwpcNQvnkLs1vqkI1LPQ20O
password from db: $2a$10$T73cIRlzbtC8Jc3ROBR8euci48VhUha5XxnHZP/lbL1PNgdGRUKAm

Comment: Это очень странно, как у вас тогда пользователь вообще авторизуется?

Comment: На данный момент, я не отлично знаю securiry. Предложу вам банальное решение, продебажте авторизацию пользователя, там тоже идет ввод пароля и сравнение со значением из БД, и повторите это действия для смены пароля. Возможно позже зайдет человек лучше разбирающийся, а пока так постарался помочь.

Answer (score 1):

в итоге все просто как никогда...

```
if (bCryptPasswordEncoder.matches(currentPassword, user.getPassword()))
```

currentPassword - строка из формы
user.getPassword() - пароль из бд